# Android app, slow rotation

Tags: android, orientation

My android app takes about 3-5 seconds before it actually rotates. The whole activity is just too big to post here. Can anyone provide me some general suggestions that can make this better? Thanks all.

Comment: The most general suggestion : speed up time somehow near the phone ( using the laws of general relativity ). That being said, don't do a lot of stuff in your life-cycle methods like onCreate, onSaveIntanceState etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's actually makes a lot of sense

Comment: The first part right? Hahaha

Comment: One more follow up question, the UI is relatively complicated. I mean it's like loading the UI itself would cause the app to skip frames, do you think that causes the rotation slow?

Comment: I dunno, it's possible. Maybe you use a lot of nested linears, with weights and stuff. Try simplifying the layout,  for example by using relative layout instead of nested linears.